# Not able to set the state properly in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react and was practicing fetching data from an API and storing it in the state but whenever I call this function it gets stuck into a loop where it is logging state every single time. So, please do tell me where I am doing wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { APP_ID, API_KEY } from "./auth";

import Navbar from "./components/navbar/navbar";
import FoodFeed from "./components/food-feed/foodFeed";

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            recipes: []
        };
    }

    //Problem here

    getRecipe = async QUERY => {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${QUERY}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${API_KEY}`
        );
        const data = await response.json();
        this.setState({ recipes: [...data.hits] });
        console.log(this.state.recipes);
    };

    render() {
        this.getRecipe("chicken");
        return (
            <>
                <Navbar />
                <FoodFeed />
            </>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: you not setState in render.
call render method after each setState().

you  can call this.getRecipe("chicken") in componentDidMount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting state triggers a re-render. You’re calling your fetch from inside render, which triggers a setState, which triggers a render, which calls a fetch, which calls setState, which triggers a render…

You should do your data fetching in one of the [lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), like [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Your component will need to do something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      recipes: []
    }
  }

  getRecipes () => async QUERY => {...}

  componentDidMount () {
    // called once after the component mounts
    const recipes = this.getRecipes();
    this.setState({ recipes });
  }

  render () {
    // this.state.recipes will be empty initially but this will update
    // when you call setState after fetching the data.
    const {recipes} = this.state;
    return (
      <Food recipes={recipes} /> // or whatever
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: so how can I store value to state without using setState? as we cannot mutate the state directly so how?

Comment: You can't call setState from inside render or you'll get an infinite loop, as you've seen.

Comment: Thank you! I directly mutated the state in my function. Is this can also be the way to store my data into state or is this a wrong practice?

Comment: You shouldn't mutate state directly. Always use `setState` to modify component state.

Comment: For tinkering and for simple projects storing data in component state is fine; for more complex projects you'll probably want to rethink this approach and delegate data fetching and storage to a dedicated store outside the component. There are myriad ways to do this. [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/) is a very common off-the-shelf approach, but might be overkill depending on your needs.

Comment: I think just realized what you were asking regarding mutating state within your function. Calling `setState` from inside your `getRecipe` function is perfectly fine.

Comment: okay! but what if I want it to be get called on a specific event then should I bind this inside `componentWillUpdate` ? and I also want these value to be passed down as props to other components is it possible to fetch these values into props after event gets triggered? Sorry if I am asking silly questions :(

Comment: No! by mutating I meant directly like this `this.state.recipes = [...data.hits];`

Comment: Don't do that. See my [other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57932554/not-able-to-set-the-state-properly-in-react/57932576?noredirect=1#comment102282209_57932583).

Comment: What do you mean by "called on a specific event"? You can trigger your getRecipe method however you want as long as you don't invoke it during render. `<button onClick={() => this.getRecipe('chicken)}>Get Chicken</button>` is fine (and common). I'm happy to continue this for a bit but continuing in the comments probably isn't the right place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `setState` renders the UI, which means it will call render method. Now, In `render` method you are doing `getReceipe`, which in-turn calls setState again, which will call render again.

Also, setState is async method. If you print log just after setState you will not get updated result. To get updated result after `setState` use it's callback method.

```
setState({
// set the state here
}, ()=> {
// get your updated state here
})
```

Use `componentDidMount` method to fetch your receipe data from server.

Comment: Thank you! Apart from that, if I directly store this data into the state in my function i.e this.state.recipes = [...data.hits]; is this wrong?

Comment: Don't do that. React relies on `setState` to trigger updates, etc., and if you mutate state directly (e.g. `this.state.recipes = [...]`) you're bypassing fundamental react functionality and will get strange behavior at best.